# Counting the amount of messages a user sent after a date with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm trying to create a bot that allows you to retrieve the number of messages a user sent in a specific channel. I know `channel.history()` is a thing but I'm not sure if I can specify a date as a parameter. Is there a way you can count the number of messages a user sent in a specific channel after a given date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing my answer off [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history) documentation. You can find details on a lot of the discord.py library there.

Yes, there is an `after` parameter for `channel.history`. It takes a `datetime` object.
Here's a quick example:

```py
import datetime

# Get yesterdays date.
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
counter = 0
# Make sure `limit` is set to None otherwise not all messages will be fetched.
async for message in channel.history(limit=None, after=yesterday):
    if message.author = some_user:
        counter += 1
```

Be wary, that this code may not work outright, don't just copy and paste it. Try to understand what it is doing. Good luck with your coding adventures!