# How to see how much messages has been sent by a role In the past 28 days? Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How to get how many messages have been sent by a role, I tried doing it myself but it didn't work out for me can anyone help me. This is what I came up with:

```
@commands.command()
async def messsagesrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history():
        if message.author == role:
            counter += 1
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} sent {counter} messages.')
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481517/counting-the-amount-of-messages-a-user-sent-after-a-date-with-discord-py) help you?

Answer (score 0):

We can check how many messages a role has sent by iterating through all of the messages in a given channel. When we view a [TextChannel's History](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) method, we can bypass the message limit by setting `limit` to `None`. We can also ensure that all of our messages are within 28 days from today by subtracting a [TimeDelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object from [Now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now). From there, we can just check if the author had the role that we're looking for and add one to our counter.

```py
import datetime
import discord

@client.command()
async def messages_role(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    messages = 0

    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    days = datetime.timedelta(days=28)

    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=None,
                                             after=today - days):
        if role in message.author.roles:
            messages += 1

    await ctx.send(f"The {role.name} role has sent {messages} messages in this channel.")
```